# Amazon s3 form post/upload redirecting to bucket after success on iOS safari/chrome only how to stop?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile, amazon-s3, safari

I have a web app that allows users to upload photos to an S3 bucket via HTML form.  It works exactly as expected on all desktop browsers, which is to do nothing after a successful upload.  However in iOS safari and iOS chrome, it redirects to the bucket.  If I "Handoff" the page over to safari on my mac it is an xml response of the entire bucket, it appears.

Does anyone know why this would happen and how to fix it?  Normally I can find something via google and the forums but I'm finding nothing!

We are not specifying "success action redirect" or "success action status" on our form.

Also, it works as expected in chrome on an android device.

We do not want any sort of redirect to occurs, we handle things on the client after clicking the submit/post button.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="mainContent">
 <form action="https://s3.amazonaws.com/{!awsKeySet.Name}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="hidden"  name="key"  id="key" /> 
    <input type="hidden"  name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{!awsKeySet.AWS_AccessKey_Id__c}" /> 
    <input type="hidden"  name="policy" value="{!policy}" /> 
    <input type="hidden"  name="signature" value="{!signedPolicy}" /> 
    <input type="hidden"  name="acl" value="{!acessType}" /> 
    <input type="hidden"  name="Content-Type" value="{!Content_Type}" /> 
    <!--input type="hidden"  name="success_action_status" value="201" /--> 

    <!--input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{!ForRedirect}" /-->

    <h4 class="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload in AWS</h4><br />
    <div class="row">
          <input type="file" size="50" name="file" id="file"  />
    </div>

    <div id="fileName"></div>
    <div id="fileSize"></div>
    <div id="fileType"></div>

    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload"  id="btn_submit" />
    </div>
   <div id="progressNumber"></div>
</form> 
</div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () { 

            var _requestBucket;

            $("#btn_submit").click(function(event){
                //alert(1);
                    event.preventDefault();
                  var _file;

                _file = $("#file").val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, "");

               console.log('_file '+ _file);
               $("#key").val(_file);

               $("#uploadForm").submit(); 


            });



     });


</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: @ceejayoz is right we need to see some code. Or even better, simplify your issue into a shareable demo and create a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: Edit it into your question, not the comments. We need to see the "handle things on the client" bit, which is presumably JavaScript.

Comment: Done, thank you!  Again.  I did find this question from a year and a half ago but no answers to it!

Comment: Could it be CORS related in the bucket settings?  I don't have access to the s3 bucket cli to make changes.  Some general direction would be super helpful!

Comment: You'll have a much easier time using HTML5 + AJAX file uploads via JS. https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/

Comment: Ceejayoz, I'm in Salesforce, lightning and right now it doesn't let you do that.  Two or three months more and we can!  Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I wish someone could have shed more light on this but sadly, this is a bug in iOS webkit browsers.  It appears to have been fixed in Android and Desktop.  So, if anyone stumbles on this problem, included is the bugzilla link for it

[Bugzilla link for Proper handling of HTTP 204](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60206)

More detail : According to the amazon s3 docs

> If the value is set to 200 or 204, Amazon S3 returns an empty document with a 
>   200 or 204 status code.
>
> If the value is set to 201, Amazon S3 returns an XML document with a
>   201 status code.
>
> If the value is not set or if it is set to an invalid value, Amazon S3
>   returns an empty document with a 204 status code.

According to HTTP 1.1 -

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> **If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.**
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

This is not happening in either webkit browsers for iOS, currently.  Sadly.  I cannot find a way around this, other for Apple to fix it!